# Changing variable name for menu items in TaskFreak

Tags: php

I installed Taskfreak 0.6.4 multiuser version and uploaded it onto my server.

From the code below, how can I rename the menu items (project, task, all_projects, future_tasks, past_tasks)? I want to replace "**project**" with "**File**" and "**task**" with "**correspondence**".

The code below is from the file header.php in the directory root/include/html.

```
<?php
// -------------- NAV MENU ---------------------------------------------------
      $pTmpLink = Tzn::concatUrl($_SESSION['linkItems'],'sProject=0');
?>
        <div id="menu">
          <ul id="nav" class="level0">               
            <li><?php echo $langMenu['task']; ?>
              <ul class="level1">
                <?php
                    if ($objUser->checkLevel(11)) {
                ?>
                <li><a href="javascript:freak_new()" accesskey="n"><?php echo $langMenu['new_todo']; ?></a></li>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
                <li><a href="javascript:freak_print()"><?php echo $langMenu['print_list']; ?></a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><?php echo $langMenu['view']; ?>
              <ul id="nav_projects" class="level1">
                <li class="more"><a href="<?php echo Tzn::concatUrl($pTmpLink,'show=today'); ?>" accesskey="l"><?php echo $langMenu['all_projects']; ?></a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo Tzn::concatUrl($pTmpLink,'show=future'); ?>" accesskey="f"><?php echo $langMenu['future_tasks']; ?></a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo Tzn::concatUrl($pTmpLink,'show=past'); ?>" accesskey="p"><?php echo $langMenu['past_tasks']; ?></a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo Tzn::concatUrl($pTmpLink,'show=all'); ?>" accesskey="a"><?php echo $langMenu['all_tasks']; ?></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              <?php
                while ($objProj = $objUserProjectList->rNext()) {
                    $pTmpLink = Tzn::concatUrl($_SESSION['linkItems'],'sProject='.$objProj->id);
              ?>
                <li class="more"><a href="<?php echo Tzn::concatUrl($pTmpLink,'show=today'); ?>"><?php $objProj->p('name'); ?></a>
                  <ul class="level2">
                    <li><a href="<?php echo Tzn::concatUrl($pTmpLink,'show=future')?>"><?php echo $langMenu['future_tasks']; ?></a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo Tzn::concatUrl($pTmpLink,'show=past')?>"><?php echo $langMenu['past_tasks']; ?></a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo Tzn::concatUrl($pTmpLink,'show=all')?>"><?php echo $langMenu['all_tasks']; ?></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              <?php
                }
              ?>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><?php echo $langMenu['manage']; ?>
              <ul class="level1">
                <li><a href="project_list.php"><?php echo $langMenu['projects']; ?></a></li>
                <?php
                if ($objUser->checkLevel(1)) {
                ?>
                <li><a href="user_list.php"><?php echo $langMenu['users']; ?></a></li>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
                <li><a href="user_edit.php?id=<?php echo $objUser->id; ?>"><?php echo $langMenu['preferences']; ?></a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="rightmenu">
            <a href="<?php echo Tzn::concatUrl($_SESSION['linkItems'],'sUser='.$objUser->id); ?>"><?php echo $langMenu['my_tasks']; ?></a> | 
            <a href="<?php echo Tzn::concatUrl($_SESSION['linkItems'],'sUser=all'); ?>"><?php echo $langMenu['all_users']; ?></a> | 
            <?php
                if ($objUser->checkLevel(1)) {
                    $objUserList->qSelect('sUser','getShortName()',$_SESSION['selUser'],
                        $langMenu['all_users'],'','onChange="this.form.submit()"');
                    $objUserList->rReset();
                    echo ' | ';
                }
                if (@constant('FRK_CONTEXT_ENABLE')) {
                    $objContextList = new ItemContextList();
                    $objContextList->qSelect('sContext',$pContext,$langMenu['all_contexts'],'','onChange="this.form.submit()"');
                }
            ?>
            <a id="lnkRefresh" href="<?php echo $_SESSION['linkItems']; ?>" title="<?php echo $langMenu['reload']; ?>"><img id="frk_status" src="skins/<?php echo FRK_SKIN_FOLDER; ?>/images/loading.gif" width="14" height="14" border="0" /></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php
```

I will appreciate your help.

Joseph

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I just needed more time to study the source code.

Now I have resolved it.

Thanx.